# calling image in grid view from sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, gridview

I am beginner in this,

I created the simple table in sql having all the filed types are 'varchar'
except id[int] and action [image].
[www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/db.png](http://www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/db.png)

question 1: how I place the path of images in action column, coz when I do its give me error (check the sql image)

I connected the gridview with visual studio wizard and its look fine.except to do the image colume
[www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/vs.png](http://www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/vs.png)

I find some article ' upload and display image in gridview' or 'display image in specific number of row'

Again I am new in this, so help me to find the solution to do as in this image.
(red box is the image which I want)
[www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/final.png](http://www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/final.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'image' type in SQL is a binary type, i.e. it is the actual data for an image, not a file path. That is why you are getting an error.

Unless you know how to read and write binary image data, I would suggest changing the 'action' field type to VARCHAR and storing the path to the image instead.

Also note that if the images are from your website project, you should store them as paths relative to the site, and load them using Server.MapPath, i.e.

```
img.Src = Server.MapPath("~/images/test.png");
```

Comment: do you have any idea, how to do the dropdown menu as shown in http://www.faisaljanjua.com/project/jk/final.png?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageField` in `Gridview` instead of using `BoundField`.. and in your SQL Database, the data type for your image is `VARCHAR` and not `Byte`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this. Insert the path of the image in a varchar field of DB. Or else directly store the image into DB as bytes.

I hope the first method don't need any explanation. If you are looking for the second option i found you a [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817552/adding-an-image-to-sql-database-using-visual-c-sharp). Look at the last comment which is marked as answer in the link .