# How to insert image to database in Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, image

With the below code i am able to insert datas to database.I have a tabel called class with 4 fields calssid, classname, description and img. classid is primary key and autoincrement so need nothing to do for it.As in the code below i have inserted classname and description but left img filed emplty.

So how do I insert image?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = @"Data Source=SUMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=school;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" select * from class", con);
    SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("insert into class values('class10','i am from class 10','')",con);
    con.Open();
    insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
 }
```

Please note that what i am asking is if i can upload image directly from here just like i uploaded other fields by providing link to image stored in some folder of my project.

I am not seeking to store image in database by uploading image.

Comment: this is already answered, use below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817552/adding-an-image-to-sql-database-using-visual-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do it. Try searching for "How to store images in sql server C#". Picking one that I felt looked reasonable: http://www.shabdar.org/sql-server/105-store-save-images-in-sql-server.html