# Insert Jpg format in SQL Server in UWP

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I do it using this code for insert JPG format in SQL Server.

```
conn.Open();

if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = SqlString;
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.).Value =;
        // .....
    }
}
```

I tried add this line of code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.).Value =;
```

In the code line I tried to put after the same Photo (control image).

I need help on how to do it.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = yourJpegAfterConvertingToByteArray;` Side notes: `if (conn.State ==...` is unnecessary, of course it's opened, you just opened it. `cmd.Parameters.Clear();` is unnecessary. You can simplify to `using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, conn))`. I hope `conn` has a `using` also.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817552/adding-an-image-to-sql-database-using-visual-c-sharp) answer your question ?

Answer (score -1):

As an addition to Charlieface's comment. You need to convert the JPG image into `Byte Array` and store it in the database as `VarBinary` type.

When you want to read the JPG image in sql, you need read the `VarBinary` data, and then convert it into `BitmapImage`, which can be used as the source of the Image control to display the picture.

The following code sample provides methods for converting JPG image into Byte Array and converting Byte Array into BitmapImage.

```
public async Task<byte[]> JpgToArrayAsync(StorageFile Jpgfile)
{
    using (var inputStream = await Jpgfile.OpenSequentialReadAsync())
    {
        var readStream = inputStream.AsStreamForRead();
        var byteArray = new byte[readStream.Length];
        await readStream.ReadAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        return byteArray;
    }
}

public async Task<BitmapImage> ArrayToBitmapImageAsync(byte[] byteArray)
{
    using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
    {
        await stream.WriteAsync(byteArray.AsBuffer());
        stream.Seek(0);
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        return image;
    }
}
```

---

#### Upadte 7/6/2023

Save jpg from data in Data Base

```
var savePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation =
    Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
// Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPG File", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
// Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New picture";

Windows.Storage.StorageFile savefile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
            
    Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(savefile);
    // write byte datas to jpg file
    // bte is the data you get from DataBase
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(savefile, bte);
            
    Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus status =
        await Windows.Storage.CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(savefile);
    if (status == Windows.Storage.Provider.FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(status);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(status);
    }
}
else
{
          
    Debug.WriteLine("Operation cancelled.");
}
```

Comment: There's no need to convert anything and certainly not to BMP. Just read the bytes with `File.ReadAllBytes`. `varbinary` and `varbinary(max)` don't care about the contents. Neither does GDI+/System.Graphis, or any other image library. .NET supports JPG natively since the very first release

Comment: Even better, if you're reading from a stream you can pass it directly to `SqlParameter` as the `Value` and it will read it.

Comment: How can I according to the code that I have to put to save the jpg format after the Value

Comment: You can refer to my update in answer. It uses [Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteBytesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileio.writebytesasync?view=winrt-22621) to write byte data to file.

Comment: According to the code I have as I can add to save in jpg format